# Get NFT transaction history

Tags: transactions, nfts, react

I'm implementing a web tool using React and I want to show to the user the transaction history of a given NFT. How can I retrieve those information?

**Update:**

Let's do a practical example. Using Devnet take this NFT address "JDjL1MmepmWcjPXndyAP8K9L77hg8Lti4DwAdTbf3Wa6" which is part of a CM created by the address "Fzm344Gh6dW4wMcEFUacbNfFBmjccwaxuPU3uHRz1caK". This is just for info but I don't need it for the result.

- The minter's address is "HEmvHx7w6T4ukiwNyS5MYyBvecjCVyDArHRu265dRHue"
- Then I made a transaction to send the NFT back to "Fzm344Gh6dW4wMcEFUacbNfFBmjccwaxuPU3uHRz1caK".

Using `connection.getConfirmedSignaturesForAddress2(mint);` where "mint" is the NFT address (correct?) I receive those signatures:

- 4QndFLpT2SiGPUur7oQDH7Y1uLSLQVtiEEE2QuyD1a3EteEmxriy2r5fYdcV4xxy5oHfwP2whd5es93FwJFcAwuE (mint)
- 4gGNW4gN2HCeDVn3cBw4BYidQmcqqzako1KMLp3dH4uZoYHE1AToGQsDbMAUCJdU9UQSRsGAWWmBkDcmisCniApB (transfer)

What I need to retrieve for each is:

1. From address (except for mint where will be empty)
2. To address
3. Date time

Comment: Is there an API to only get transfer i.e., A wallet to B wallet transactions in one go on solana

Comment: @user3394 Is this a question or an affirmation?

Comment: Did you solve this problem, I have the same development needs

Answer (score 7):

Alongside https://www.npmjs.com/package/@metaplex-foundation/js in retrieving the given NFT's information, you need to:

1. Obtain the signatures for the account first. (Signatures are basically the Tx IDs)
   https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getsignaturesforaddress

Example:

```
curl http://localhost:8899 -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "getSignaturesForAddress",
    "params": [
      "Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111",
      {
        "limit": 1
      }
    ]
  }
'
```

2. Then https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettransaction for every transaction you have iteratively. (If you want more information)

Example:

```
curl http://localhost:8899 -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "getTransaction",
    "params": [
      "2nBhEBYYvfaAe16UMNqRHre4YNSskvuYgx3M6E4JP1oDYvZEJHvoPzyUidNgNX5r9sTyN1J9UxtbCXy2rqYcuyuv",
      "json"
    ]
  }
'
```

> The first API gathers a historical list of transactions involving said token. The second API enables you to gather granular information pertaining to the specific transaction

That's about it!

Comment: Just a note, if you are trying to get any and all history for a NFT using it's PublicKey -- some programs/sites don't include it correctly in the transaction accounts array and thus you won't be able to get every single event that ever took place.

Therefore, you would need to walk back the actual program history to get every action (a non-trivial task).

Comment: This is a first step but doesn't answer totally to what I need. I have updated my question to provide a practical case. I'm not able to find some information

Answer (score 2):

You can try using Helius's "Parse Transactions(s)" API that returns parsed transactions. You can include up to 100 transaction signatures in a single request. And there's a free tier you can use.

https://docs.helius.xyz/solana-apis/enhanced-transactions-api/parse-transaction-s

```
  const parse_transaction_url = `https://api.helius.xyz/v0/transactions/?api-key=${HELIUS_KEY}`

  const { data } = await axios.post(parse_transaction_url, {
    transactions: [
      "...transaction signature here...",
    ],
  })
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))
  fs.writeFileSync(
    "parsedTransaction.json",
    JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)
  )
```

Here is an example of the data that's returned for a single transaction. The first line is a description (if it's a supported transaction type that Helius parses). There's also a unix "timestamp" and all the accounts in a format that's easier to read.

```
"description": "2vxfoajqRmZGSmcjyML5kzmwEvEVa5QQVn5orWp5xBB2 canceled a swap on FOXY_SWAP",
    "type": "CANCEL_SWAP",
    "source": "FOXY",
    "fee": 105000,
    "feePayer": "2vxfoajqRmZGSmcjyML5kzmwEvEVa5QQVn5orWp5xBB2",
    "signature": "2zDNuwiX2BdRAminGzpyNmL4BxbKD3AFnu4D6uzbTxEMPumBxozCNQNXn6mVomPjKwXt6AtsYr4tUWpoBSbNADU1",
    "slot": 160875333,
    "timestamp": 1668375746,
    "tokenTransfers": [
      {
        "fromTokenAccount": "B2RJBjv4Buz7ZUJwRDkrKbSNSY78PX1QfiM3wZokY233",
        "toTokenAccount": "8e353HYVThwoY4Ta4Wk7KzYj1rz7Vkp56CLpM2C12F7H",
        "fromUserAccount": "859MsTbcRvSyWVD6GYmfwcijti4qSpm8UYFgqcGbMT33",
        "toUserAccount": "2vxfoajqRmZGSmcjyML5kzmwEvEVa5QQVn5orWp5xBB2",
        "tokenAmount": 1,
        "mint": "3rEDfQMnQUuR6HQ3JxT4eEPx2Rmz5X6pBJCUTLkeFdiN",
        "tokenStandard": "NonFungible"
      }
    ],
    "nativeTransfers": [
      {
        "fromUserAccount": "2vxfoajqRmZGSmcjyML5kzmwEvEVa5QQVn5orWp5xBB2",
        "toUserAccount": "8e353HYVThwoY4Ta4Wk7KzYj1rz7Vkp56CLpM2C12F7H",
        "amount": 2039280
      },
      {
        "fromUserAccount": "859MsTbcRvSyWVD6GYmfwcijti4qSpm8UYFgqcGbMT33",
        "toUserAccount": "2vxfoajqRmZGSmcjyML5kzmwEvEVa5QQVn5orWp5xBB2",
        "amount": 20000000
      }
    ],
    "accountData": [
      {
        "account": "2vxfoajqRmZGSmcjyML5kzmwEvEVa5QQVn5orWp5xBB2",
        "nativeBalanceChange": 23959640,
        "tokenBalanceChanges": []
      },
      {
        "account": "3Hf2qU2sUdhighGzHqXv7T5EEgz8yBNrjVV64YXmVpLt",
        "nativeBalanceChange": -4064640,
        "tokenBalanceChanges": []
      },
      {
        "account": "859MsTbcRvSyWVD6GYmfwcijti4qSpm8UYFgqcGbMT33",
        "nativeBalanceChange": -20000000,
        "tokenBalanceChanges": []
      },
      {
        "account": "8e353HYVThwoY4Ta4Wk7KzYj1rz7Vkp56CLpM2C12F7H",
        "nativeBalanceChange": 2039280,
        "tokenBalanceChanges": [
          {
            "userAccount": "2vxfoajqRmZGSmcjyML5kzmwEvEVa5QQVn5orWp5xBB2",
            "tokenAccount": "8e353HYVThwoY4Ta4Wk7KzYj1rz7Vkp56CLpM2C12F7H",
            "rawTokenAmount": {
              "tokenAmount": "1",
              "decimals": 0
            },
            "mint": "3rEDfQMnQUuR6HQ3JxT4eEPx2Rmz5X6pBJCUTLkeFdiN"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "account": "B2RJBjv4Buz7ZUJwRDkrKbSNSY78PX1QfiM3wZokY233",
        "nativeBalanceChange": -2039280,
        "tokenBalanceChanges": [
          {
            "userAccount": "859MsTbcRvSyWVD6GYmfwcijti4qSpm8UYFgqcGbMT33",
            "tokenAccount": "B2RJBjv4Buz7ZUJwRDkrKbSNSY78PX1QfiM3wZokY233",
            "rawTokenAmount": {
              "tokenAmount": "-1",
              "decimals": 0
            },
            "mint": "3rEDfQMnQUuR6HQ3JxT4eEPx2Rmz5X6pBJCUTLkeFdiN"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "account": "Mc5XB47H3DKJHym5RLa9mPzWv5snERsF3KNv5AauXK8",
        "nativeBalanceChange": 0,
        "tokenBalanceChanges": []
      },
      {
        "account": "11111111111111111111111111111111",
        "nativeBalanceChange": 0,
        "tokenBalanceChanges": []
      },
      {
        "account": "3rEDfQMnQUuR6HQ3JxT4eEPx2Rmz5X6pBJCUTLkeFdiN",
        "nativeBalanceChange": 0,
        "tokenBalanceChanges": []
      },
      {
        "account": "8guzmt92HbM7yQ69UJg564hRRX6N4nCdxWE5L6ENrA8P",
        "nativeBalanceChange": 0,
        "tokenBalanceChanges": []
      },
      {
        "account": "ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL",
        "nativeBalanceChange": 0,
        "tokenBalanceChanges": []
      },
      {
        "account": "ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111",
        "nativeBalanceChange": 0,
        "tokenBalanceChanges": []
      },
      {
        "account": "SysvarRent111111111111111111111111111111111",
        "nativeBalanceChange": 0,
        "tokenBalanceChanges": []
      },
      {
        "account": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
        "nativeBalanceChange": 0,
        "tokenBalanceChanges": []
      }
    ],
    "transactionError": null,
    "instructions": [
      {
        "accounts": [
          "3Hf2qU2sUdhighGzHqXv7T5EEgz8yBNrjVV64YXmVpLt",
          "859MsTbcRvSyWVD6GYmfwcijti4qSpm8UYFgqcGbMT33",
          "2vxfoajqRmZGSmcjyML5kzmwEvEVa5QQVn5orWp5xBB2",
          "Mc5XB47H3DKJHym5RLa9mPzWv5snERsF3KNv5AauXK8",
          "8e353HYVThwoY4Ta4Wk7KzYj1rz7Vkp56CLpM2C12F7H",
          "3rEDfQMnQUuR6HQ3JxT4eEPx2Rmz5X6pBJCUTLkeFdiN",
          "B2RJBjv4Buz7ZUJwRDkrKbSNSY78PX1QfiM3wZokY233",
          "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
          "ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL",
          "SysvarRent111111111111111111111111111111111",
          "11111111111111111111111111111111"
        ],
        "data": "QsTzMXR9thh",
        "programId": "8guzmt92HbM7yQ69UJg564hRRX6N4nCdxWE5L6ENrA8P",
        "innerInstructions": [
          {
            "accounts": [
              "2vxfoajqRmZGSmcjyML5kzmwEvEVa5QQVn5orWp5xBB2",
              "8e353HYVThwoY4Ta4Wk7KzYj1rz7Vkp56CLpM2C12F7H",
              "2vxfoajqRmZGSmcjyML5kzmwEvEVa5QQVn5orWp5xBB2",
              "3rEDfQMnQUuR6HQ3JxT4eEPx2Rmz5X6pBJCUTLkeFdiN",
              "11111111111111111111111111111111",
              "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA"
            ],
            "data": "1",
            "programId": "ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL"
          },
          {
            "accounts": ["3rEDfQMnQUuR6HQ3JxT4eEPx2Rmz5X6pBJCUTLkeFdiN"],
            "data": "84eT",
            "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA"
          },
          {
            "accounts": [
              "2vxfoajqRmZGSmcjyML5kzmwEvEVa5QQVn5orWp5xBB2",
              "8e353HYVThwoY4Ta4Wk7KzYj1rz7Vkp56CLpM2C12F7H"
            ],
            "data": "11119os1e9qSs2u7TsThXqkBSRVFxhmYaFKFZ1waB2X7armDmvK3p5GmLdUxYdg3h7QSrL",
            "programId": "11111111111111111111111111111111"
          },
          {
            "accounts": ["8e353HYVThwoY4Ta4Wk7KzYj1rz7Vkp56CLpM2C12F7H"],
            "data": "P",
            "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA"
          },
          {
            "accounts": [
              "8e353HYVThwoY4Ta4Wk7KzYj1rz7Vkp56CLpM2C12F7H",
              "3rEDfQMnQUuR6HQ3JxT4eEPx2Rmz5X6pBJCUTLkeFdiN"
            ],
            "data": "6P4fLjnGdicq6iFiG4WXREyDKjopJypg7ChFfM6VuFKbz",
            "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA"
          },
          {
            "accounts": [
              "B2RJBjv4Buz7ZUJwRDkrKbSNSY78PX1QfiM3wZokY233",
              "8e353HYVThwoY4Ta4Wk7KzYj1rz7Vkp56CLpM2C12F7H",
              "859MsTbcRvSyWVD6GYmfwcijti4qSpm8UYFgqcGbMT33"
            ],
            "data": "3DdGGhkhJbjm",
            "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA"
          },
          {
            "accounts": [
              "B2RJBjv4Buz7ZUJwRDkrKbSNSY78PX1QfiM3wZokY233",
              "2vxfoajqRmZGSmcjyML5kzmwEvEVa5QQVn5orWp5xBB2",
              "859MsTbcRvSyWVD6GYmfwcijti4qSpm8UYFgqcGbMT33"
            ],
            "data": "A",
            "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "accounts": [
          "3Hf2qU2sUdhighGzHqXv7T5EEgz8yBNrjVV64YXmVpLt",
          "859MsTbcRvSyWVD6GYmfwcijti4qSpm8UYFgqcGbMT33",
          "2vxfoajqRmZGSmcjyML5kzmwEvEVa5QQVn5orWp5xBB2",
          "Mc5XB47H3DKJHym5RLa9mPzWv5snERsF3KNv5AauXK8",
          "11111111111111111111111111111111"
        ],
        "data": "FqKUvefTVK6",
        "programId": "8guzmt92HbM7yQ69UJg564hRRX6N4nCdxWE5L6ENrA8P",
        "innerInstructions": [
          {
            "accounts": [
              "859MsTbcRvSyWVD6GYmfwcijti4qSpm8UYFgqcGbMT33",
              "2vxfoajqRmZGSmcjyML5kzmwEvEVa5QQVn5orWp5xBB2"
            ],
            "data": "3Bxs3ztNaW5EjZkb",
            "programId": "11111111111111111111111111111111"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "accounts": [],
        "data": "3gJqkocMWaMm",
        "programId": "ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111",
        "innerInstructions": []
      },
      {
        "accounts": [],
        "data": "FjL4FH",
        "programId": "ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111",
        "innerInstructions": []
      }
    ],
    "events": {}
  },
```

For reference, here's a raw transaction (different transaction than one above though):

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "slot": 165721272,
      "transaction": {
        "message": {
          "header": {
            "numReadonlySignedAccounts": 0,
            "numReadonlyUnsignedAccounts": 9,
            "numRequiredSignatures": 1
          },
          "accountKeys": [
            "CQHFjBf8Ar7kEgVRpGdLLGRnXN7pGSZBJys6P38LRXm6",
            "4QRgo3t3RSYJzRLUS8wkXdCb586HRxLGRuu2wZiTSXsN",
            "8XPWBaMWcTEmKpctUYBbeAzFgi6UvzDjWhxiuyzPdAAG",
            "CVRKhznijFG7jVyiZa8eeXrD1dzeE6Psn3YzLLgd5f52",
            "FifJQ3ZjZBKh9h4ugUdza1rtmYwGZCDFoZJbL2cEzTX5",
            "11111111111111111111111111111111",
            "9AhKqLR67hwapvG8SA2JFXaCshXc9nALJjpKaHZrsbkw",
            "ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL",
            "ENicYBBNZQ91toN7ggmTxnDGZW14uv9UkumN7XBGeYJ4",
            "EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v",
            "FudPMePeNqmnjMX19zEKDfGXpbp6HAdW6ZGprB5gYRTZ",
            "JBGUGPmKUEHCpxGGoMowQxoV4c7HyqxEnyrznVPxftqk",
            "SysvarRent111111111111111111111111111111111",
            "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA"
          ],
          "recentBlockhash": "EZqRonef3ftSM8Bjt5xZHt4hhoTgfzJTbuuB63SCn1x1",
          "instructions": [
            {
              "accounts": [
                0,
                2,
                3,
                1,
                4,
                6,
                10,
                11,
                9,
                12,
                13,
                7,
                5
              ],
              "data": "2PvhrZru6Gf7v4Xxdc3S7RH7FML3S7tXnBR8uMH",
              "programIdIndex": 8
            }
          ],
          "addressTableLookups": null
        },
        "signatures": [
          "2xsyZUcBPcAigMKeNbPgxWCN2BWsNL8Sd6cstNnxN3J46Lnk3MueCG7jCZpsYX6jqsHWUYq3fpj358jze8g7uGu5"
        ]
      },
      "blockTime": 1670534538,
      "meta": {
        "err": null,
        "fee": 5000,
        "preBalances": [
          48820592015,
          2039280,
          2039280,
          2039280,
          2039280,
          1,
          1138288516,
          731913600,
          1141440,
          179719266068,
          3354895880,
          561019623799,
          1009200,
          934087680
        ],
        "postBalances": [
          48820587015,
          2039280,
          2039280,
          2039280,
          2039280,
          1,
          1138288516,
          731913600,
          1141440,
          179719266068,
          3354895880,
          561019623799,
          1009200,
          934087680
        ],
        "innerInstructions": [
          {
            "index": 0,
            "instructions": [
              {
                "accounts": [
                  2,
                  3,
                  0
                ],
                "data": "3DbEuZHcyqBD",
                "programIdIndex": 13
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "preTokenBalances": [
          {
            "mint": "EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v",
            "owner": "FudPMePeNqmnjMX19zEKDfGXpbp6HAdW6ZGprB5gYRTZ",
            "accountIndex": 1,
            "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
            "uiTokenAmount": {
              "amount": "1063010005",
              "decimals": 6,
              "uiAmount": 1063.01,
              "uiAmountString": "1063.010005"
            }
          },
          {
            "mint": "EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v",
            "owner": "CQHFjBf8Ar7kEgVRpGdLLGRnXN7pGSZBJys6P38LRXm6",
            "accountIndex": 2,
            "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
            "uiTokenAmount": {
              "amount": "1001529671",
              "decimals": 6,
              "uiAmount": 1001.52966,
              "uiAmountString": "1001.529671"
            }
          },
          {
            "mint": "EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v",
            "owner": "9AhKqLR67hwapvG8SA2JFXaCshXc9nALJjpKaHZrsbkw",
            "accountIndex": 3,
            "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
            "uiTokenAmount": {
              "amount": "9000000000",
              "decimals": 6,
              "uiAmount": 9000,
              "uiAmountString": "9000"
            }
          },
          {
            "mint": "EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v",
            "owner": "JBGUGPmKUEHCpxGGoMowQxoV4c7HyqxEnyrznVPxftqk",
            "accountIndex": 4,
            "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
            "uiTokenAmount": {
              "amount": "14212579435",
              "decimals": 6,
              "uiAmount": 14212.579,
              "uiAmountString": "14212.579435"
            }
          }
        ],
        "postTokenBalances": [
          {
            "mint": "EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v",
            "owner": "FudPMePeNqmnjMX19zEKDfGXpbp6HAdW6ZGprB5gYRTZ",
            "accountIndex": 1,
            "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
            "uiTokenAmount": {
              "amount": "1063010005",
              "decimals": 6,
              "uiAmount": 1063.01,
              "uiAmountString": "1063.010005"
            }
          },
          {
            "mint": "EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v",
            "owner": "CQHFjBf8Ar7kEgVRpGdLLGRnXN7pGSZBJys6P38LRXm6",
            "accountIndex": 2,
            "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
            "uiTokenAmount": {
              "amount": "1529671",
              "decimals": 6,
              "uiAmount": 1.529671,
              "uiAmountString": "1.529671"
            }
          },
          {
            "mint": "EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v",
            "owner": "9AhKqLR67hwapvG8SA2JFXaCshXc9nALJjpKaHZrsbkw",
            "accountIndex": 3,
            "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
            "uiTokenAmount": {
              "amount": "10000000000",
              "decimals": 6,
              "uiAmount": 10000,
              "uiAmountString": "10000"
            }
          },
          {
            "mint": "EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v",
            "owner": "JBGUGPmKUEHCpxGGoMowQxoV4c7HyqxEnyrznVPxftqk",
            "accountIndex": 4,
            "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
            "uiTokenAmount": {
              "amount": "14212579435",
              "decimals": 6,
              "uiAmount": 14212.579,
              "uiAmountString": "14212.579435"
            }
          }
        ],
        "logMessages": [
          "Program ENicYBBNZQ91toN7ggmTxnDGZW14uv9UkumN7XBGeYJ4 invoke [1]",
          "Program log: Instruction: SinglePayment",
          "Program data: FP1DEbY0zs0Aypo7AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAqWdLDMMYfthrjEEsNK58IwdQkg06MqRCrFzPxC9tLAV5WVFn2kgMWuE0RQHSEbdzY0Dj+98A7N5jtk3IiswvHAYAAABTaW5nbGU=",
          "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]",
          "Program log: Instruction: Transfer",
          "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 4645 of 182618 compute units",
          "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success",
          "Program ENicYBBNZQ91toN7ggmTxnDGZW14uv9UkumN7XBGeYJ4 consumed 22868 of 200000 compute units",
          "Program ENicYBBNZQ91toN7ggmTxnDGZW14uv9UkumN7XBGeYJ4 success"
        ],
        "rewards": [],
        "loadedAddresses": {
          "writable": [],
          "readonly": []
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "paginationToken": "V1_165721272_144"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html

```
const connection = new Connection("https://ssc-dao.genesysgo.net/")
const mint = new PublicKey("H3LDPg9cJH24h7SfepxSqQrEy42qYBB9ZJAHpzXS3P5");
const sigs = await connection.getConfirmedSignaturesForAddress2(mint);
const txns = await connection.getParsedTransactions(sigs.map(i => i.signature));
```

Comment: This is a first step but doesn't answer totally to what I need. I have updated my question to provide a practical case. I'm not able to find some information