# How do you get the wallet address that initiated the minting of an NFT?

Tags: spl-token, web3.js

I have the NFT Address. I think I need to start by getting its mint authority? Searching the docs for something that will help me right now but am having no luck.

Edit1: found getMint(). Trying now.

Edit2: okay now I need to get the transaction history of the mint auth

Answer (score 1):

Start by getting the transaction history: [Get NFT transaction history](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/63/get-nft-transaction-history)

You have to get the first transaction that ever occurred with the NFT. That transaction will include an instruction to initialize a mint and the initializer will also be included.

You can use [getParsedTransaction](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getParsedTransaction) to get the transaction metadata.